# How to Create Cookies to Remember a Javascript Instruction

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

John Giotta kindly gave me this code earlier (on stack overflow) in order to implement a "turn off styles" button on my website (for a university assignment).

```
function nostyle() {
    for (i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        void(document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled=true);
    }
}
```

I was wondering how easy it would be to implement a cookie to remember that this javascript has been applied so that every page navigated after on the site has styles turned off (My knowledge is **extremely** basic, I am only a first year).

Regards

Comment: Make sure to `var` your variables so you are not setting a global variable. In the for loop, it should read `var i = 0` instead of `i = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
        + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
```

Set your `css_disabled` cookie

```
SetCookie('css_disabled', 'true', 100);
```

To read the cookie:

```
function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
    var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
    var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName+"=");
    if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
    var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind);
    if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
    return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
}

if (ReadCookie('css_disabled') == 'true') {...
```

Comment: thank you, but how do i implement this into my code, this is two years above what we are covering this year, I was just interested at how it would work, would I save the set cookie as css_disable and then.....

Comment: You'll want to first read for the cookie at page load. If the cookie isn't set you'll get an empty string and you will not disable.If and when the user disables the CSS, set the cookie to true.